# I need to apply validation on the combination of columns in laravel model rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

```
    public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'min:3|unique:enterprise,name|required',
    'lang_id'=> 'min:1|unique:lang_id',
];
```

This is rule for separate column validation but I need if either column name or lang_id is different then value should be updated

Answer (score 0):

Use the `different` validation:

> The field under validation must have a different value than field.

```
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'min:3|unique:enterprise,name|required|different:lang_id',
    'lang_id'=> 'min:1|unique:lang_id|different:name',
];
```

As found in the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-different